# Can a Delphi 4 and/or Delphi 5 executable be integrated into a C# application?

Tags: c#, delphi, integration, compatibility, legacy

Can Delphi 4 and\or 5 application functionality (.exe) be integrated into a C# application?

I've been tasked with rewriting a new application which will be based off of existing Delphi 4/5 written application, which are currently held together with a Batch Processing Script that no one at my company understands.

As an interum solution, I've been asked to investigate whether a C# GUI\wrapper can be placed on top so it's easier to maintain and run.

I know that Delphi 6 applications can be called within a C# application using reflection but I'm not entirely sure how.

So back to my original question can a Delphi 4/5 application functionality be called within a C# application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, I don't see where reflection would come into this. Are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: I've only glanced at the code a few years ago but it was explained to me that it was using reflection to call the Delphi exe and then invoking certain methods within the exe.  Unfortunately this was at a previous company and I don't have access to the code anymore.

Comment: That makes no sense. C# reflection can't work on a Delphi exe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it could work on a Dephi exe if the Delphi were compiled to an IL assembly.  See versions 8 and later here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi#Versions

Comment: @phoog That's not Delphi. That's Delphi.net, an entirely different beast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying premise of the question appears to be that a C# wrapper around a Delphi core is easier to maintain and run, and if that is not true, then the idea of creating the wrapper becomes not-very-useful.  I believe it is a wrongly-conceived notion.

Imagine that I made an application that can talk to a telescope.  It does it perfectly.  In that case, I might be able to extract just the telescope-communication part and put it in a DLL and then write a user interface in C# that uses the Delphi DLL just to do the communicate-with-telescope task. However, unless your Delphi application was already structured in a nice way, and unless a task like this telescope-communications library already exists, you won't find it very easy to extract any part of a Delphi application, and use it from C#. If that situation existed, I would use native Delphi DLL function exports and invoke them from C#.  This is not using the existing delphi executable, and requires many hours of work to refactor part of a Delphi application into something that could be used from C#.

Another answer mentions COM Servers, and while that is possible, it is not going to make things easier; Like the old joke about regular expressions; When you have a problem and try to solve it by using regular expressions, now you have two problems. The same becomes true when you try to use COM Servers to hide your existing application and write a whole new UI on top of it using C#.  It would actually take more technical skill to improve, debug, and continue to develop it that way, than to keep developing it either purely in delphi or purely in C#.  It's a negative savings of effort.

You have given no information about what the Delphi application does, but let's assume that it's a line-of-business or vertical market application that reads some file format, or does some communication protocol, or even connects to some old database, that you don't want to rewrite.

If by making the C# UI you mean, to never show the Delphi application user interface and replace it with a C# one, it is nearly certain that your idea is not going to make anything any better, and can only ever make things worse. Your deadlock either comes from not having skilled delphi developers, or else it comes from not having clever developers who can figure out what an existing application does.

The solution is usually a human solution when you are in this situation; either to hire a skilled delphi developer and bring the application forward into the modern Delphi era (Delphi XE2) or to hire a skilled non-delphi developer and port the application to some other language. Anybody who would suggest writing a "wrapper" over top of the delphi application who thinks that will make it "easier" obviously feels incapable of rewriting the existing application.

I don't know enough about what your delphi application does, to be sure, but it sure sounds to me like "fear driven" decisions.  Wrapping old code is almost never a good idea, and is most often, just the creation of more problems.

Comment: I've been tasked with rewriting the application and I have experience in maintaining & developing Delphi software. I will be porting the application over to C# as a long term solution but in the meantime I've been asked if it's possible to create a wrapper to replace the Batch Scripting Language that holds it all together.  I was asked this question by a manager who has no experience developing software of any kind.  I agree a full rewrite is the best option but I've been asked to investigate whether it is possible or not.

Comment: Well, the best option is not to rewrite it but to continue to maintain it in Delphi, after porting up to XE2. But since you've been tasked by someone with more authority than brains, I wish you luck. :-) (There are hundreds of companies rewriting their Delphi apps into C#, usually because they think they can hire more people to work for them that way. I happen to think that's nuts. Train people.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The business is a microsoft partner so they are eager to get every piece of software ported over to .NET.  Long term I believe this is the best solution as I am the only Delphi to C# developer in the business.

Comment: Totally makes sense then.  .Net is Microsoft's platform, and partners will definitely make whatever architecture changes they can, to fit into the ecosystem. C# is a great language, and .net is a fine platform.  My objecting to rewriting apps is that it's such a huge effort to get back to where you already are, no matter whether the language you rewrite to is C#, Java, or Python.  At least C#/.Net is a good target platform.

Answer (score 2):

A Delphi .exe can be run from C#. But I guess this is not your point.

You can either use a COM server, which is standard but needs the COM object to be registered on the computer (by running `regsrv32.exe`). Not so easy to deploy.

Or you can define the Delphi code as a library, then load and execute the .dll [from the C# code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301501.aspx).

If you prefer to access C# objects from Delphi 4 or 5 (that is access C# RTTI), you'll have to use some low-level unit like [Managed extensions for VCL - .Net interop for Delphi Win32](http://www.managed-vcl.com/). Which is quite complete, and works with old versions of Delphi (whereas something more high-level than [Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra/default.aspx) will not support Delphi 4 or 5, sadly).

*Edit*

Another possible easy communication is GDI messages. You can send GDI commands from your C# code to control the Delphi application, but using PostMessage() API calls.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  C# can call any .exe.  Just use Process.Start:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Comment: Not entirely what I meant.  I would like to call certain methods within the Delphi Application from a C# application.  Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @zeencat The problem is the question. You don't call methods of .exe files typically. You just run them. Unless the exe is a COM server, but you did not mention that. You need to fix the question to include some real details.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi 5 supports implementing COM server functionality (don't know about earlier versions, D2 definitely did not).

If you have the sources available,

- add a type library and a COM implementation of the interfaces defined in the type library,
- register the executable (typically done automatically on startup thanks to Delphi magic)
- follow the steps on MSDN: [Exposing COM Components to the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6tx9dw3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)